# Did Malfoy's parents go to Azkaban after the final book?

Tags: harry-potter

What we know from the movies and the books is that Malfoy's parents had assisted Lord Voldemort, we also know that Malfoy's father was a Death Eater but we do not know whether his mother was though.

My question is, after the final book and the war was over did Malfoy's parents go to Azkaban for assisting Lord Voldemort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, they did not.

Because Narcissa directly betrayed Voldemort by lying about the death of Harry Potter and because [Lucius provided testimony that led to the capture of several Death Eaters](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-malfoy-family) the family was pardoned and spent no additional time in Azkaban.